# Detect what button is pressed

Tags: flutter, button, attributes, handler

Suppose there are several buttons created programmatically, and there is a common button handler.

```
onButtonClicked(){
// print button attribute
}
```

How to understand inside the handler which button is pressed?

**WITHOUT passing something special inside the function call**. That won't do:
`onButtonClicked("button" + i);`

In JavaScript, for example, inside the handler, there is `$(this)`, which immediately "understands" which button is pressed.

Maybe there is a similar mechanism in Flutter?  I want to hang attributes on the button (without knowing which ones in advance), and then have access to them in the handler.

Comment: Can you include more details about how you are generating buttons and calling `onPressed`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have real example. I just try to build my first app.  It will be some foreach in json parser, that will generate several buttons with attributes taken from json.

Comment: Then I think you will get unique property from JSON, and based on it, you can set up condition for it. Sorry but you don't have any issue yet, please try to implement your code , share the efforts you put to solve the issue and some of us might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one way to write the print('your function name') inside your function

Comment: but I need button attribute, any of them

Comment: you want to response on consule right?

Comment: don't understand the questiuon. I waте to make some kind of function, that will haму acess to dynamic built attributes of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the Parameter inside your method.
for example:-

```
 onButtonClicked(Parameter){
  // print button attribute
  print("${parameter}");
}
```

And pass different parameter for different buttons.

Comment: I need about 50 parameters in future,  and at the beginnig I don't know it names.  Then, I don't want to edit code each time  I need to add one more parameter.